# Spring cloud gateway multiple filters

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to configure multiple filters in SCG, some in Java code and some via configuration. Is this possible to have a request to get filters by multiple filters? I ask this because every filters takes an argument `url` that must to pointing to a service URL or any upsteam URL. And if any 1st filters predicates_true by any request that it'll route that request to ustream URL and hence 2nd filter(be it in Java code or conf) wont get triggered.

Problem:
1st filter:

```
.route("decrypt_request_encrypt_response", r -> r
                        .asyncPredicate(serverWebExchange -> {
                            return Mono.just(Arrays.stream(RouterProperties.getProperty("enc.dec.paths").split(",")).filter(path -> serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().contains(path)).findFirst().isPresent());
                        })
                        .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/")
                                .modifyRequestBody(String.class, String.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                        (exchange, s) -> Mono.just(aesEncryption.decrypt(s)))
                        )
                        .uri("lb://misc-service1"))
```

2nd filer:

```
gateway:
            routes:
                - id: test1
                  uri: http://localhost:9900/
                  predicates:
                      - Path=/
                      - Weight=group1,9
                - id: test2
                  uri: http://localhost:9901/
                  predicates:
                      - Path=/
                      - Weight=group1,1
```

Is it possible to route a request to from 1st filter to 2nd filter?

Comment: Routes are defined either in the java dsl or the configuration, they can not be merged.

Comment: @spencergibb, even if I define 2 routes in conf. Can a request get filtered by both routes if it passes both route's predicate?